# Setting a UISearchBar from a Xib does not show the search bar on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5, uisearchbar

Context: Xcode 4.5.2, Interface Builder, autolayout disabled

When a UISearchBar is added as a child of a UITableViewController, the search bar displays properly on iOS 6 but not at all on iOS 5. The following bug report describes the issue:

http://openradar.appspot.com/12707740

Can anyone suggest a workaround for this?

*Object Hierarchy in Interface Builder:*
[image: Object hierarchy in Interface Builder]

*Appearance in Interface Builder:*
[image: Appearance in Interface Builder]

*Appearance in iPhone 6 Simulator:*
[image: Appearance in iPhone 6 Simulator]

*Appearance in iPhone 5.1 Simulator:*
[image: Appearance in iPhone 5.1 Simulator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the UITableViewController object, you must initialize it using the nib file name:

```
 TableViewControllerObject *tableViewControllerObject = [[TableViewControllerObject alloc]initWithNibName:@"TableViewControllerObject" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Yes! Worked perfectly. Thanks for this and apologies for taking a bit to mark correct.